# How to get time of last read from all Kafka topics?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have Kafka Consumer(java), and 200 topics in Kafka.
I should get time of last read from all topics for statistic in my Kafka Consumer.

Could you help me?

Comment: Please check this oss tool by uber https://eng.uber.com/chaperone/ Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It's not clear what you've tried already